# Email sending error in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am working on a project that needs to send email.I use this as my controller

```
$from_email = $this->input->post('email'); 
$to_email = "info@test.com"; 
$name = $this->input->post('name'); 
$phno = $this->input->post('phno'); 
$from = $this->input->post('start');
$to = $this->input->post('end');
$message = $this->input->post('message');
    $bodyContent="<table>
    <tr><td>Name:</td><td>$name</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Phno:</td><td>$phno</td></tr>
    <tr><td>From Date:</td><td>$from</td><td>To Date:</td><td>$to</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Message:</td><td>$message</td></tr>
    </table>";
//Load email library 
    $this->load->library('email'); 
    $this->email->from($from_email, $name); 
    $this->email->to($to_email);
    $this->email->subject('Enquiry From Test TOURS'); 
    $this->email->message($bodyContent); 
//Send mail 
if($this->email->send()) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata("email_sent","Email sent successfully."); 
} else {
    $this->session->set_flashdata("email_sent","Error in sending Email."); 
}
redirect('test_view/index');
```

And I am getting the output in the mail as like this

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Name:</td><td>wer</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Phno:</td><td>wer</td></tr>
    <tr><td>From Date:</td><td>10/18/2017</td><td>To
    Date:</td><td>10/25/2017</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Message:</td><td>wer</td></tr>
</table>
```

I don't know why i am getting output in the mail like this , can anyone sortout this error please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `mailtype` configuration 'html' in Email configuration file

```
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
```

from [user guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#email-preferences)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the type as html :

> $this->email->set_mailtype("html");

Comment: Sorrry ,I didnt get that.